# Using Custom Settings in Apex Trigger to Call Different Values for Sandbox/Production

Tags: apex, trigger, customsetting, bestpractice, design-patterns

I have an Apex Trigger for a Salesforce integration that looks like this in the Sandbox environment:

```
trigger Trigger_5074086a_493f_48d2_a8fd on Opportunity (after insert, after update, after delete, after undelete) {

    String url = 'https://test.dev.wi.com/api/hook/agh0UD9J0kio_Qd';
    String accessKey = '2c072ad68ac3039fca9fa868a3033f95ea165213136f';

    String content;

    if (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate || Trigger.isUndelete) {
        content = wiWebHook.json(Trigger.newMap.keySet());
    } else {
        content = wiWebHook.json(Trigger.oldMap.keySet());
    }

    wiWebHook.callout(url, content, accessKey);
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that the string URL and Access Key are hard coded in the Trigger and they are only valid for my Dev Site. The String URL and Access Key is different for Production.

I have created a Custom Settings object called WILead__c with 2 fields which each contain the correct URL:

String_URL_Dev__c has a value of

> https://test.dev.wi.com/api/hook/agh0UD9J0kio_Qd

String_URL_Live__c has a value of

> https://test.production.wi.com/api/hook/agh0UD9J0kio_Qd

I have also created a Custom Settings object called WIAccessKey__c with 2 fields which each contain the correct access key:

WIAccessKey__c.String_Access_Key_Dev__c has a value of

> 2c072ad68ac3039fca9fa868a3033f95ea165213136f

WIAccessKey__c.String_Access_Key_Live__c has a value of

> 128jkg785788ddff559939fca9fa868a3033f95ea165

My question is, how do I update my Trigger code so that when the Trigger is used in Sandbox it uses the WILead__c.String_URL_Dev__c and WIAccessKey__c.String_Access_Key_Dev__c values, and when it is run in Production it uses the WILead__c.String_URL_Live__c and WIAccessKey__c.String_Access_Key_Live__c values?

Comment: I'm not sure you should post your endpoints and access keys publicly...

Comment: Hi Adrian, thanks for heads up, but they are not valid endpoints or access keys - I "doctored" them before I posted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I recommend you use a `Hierarchy Custom Setting` to store default configuration like you have here. They are better suited to the task than `List Custom Settings`. It's not clear based on your post which you are using.

Second, I would remove `String` from your field names. It is redundant and makes your code extra verbose. I also recommend strongly *against* separate fields for `Dev`/`Live`. That's why you're using a `Custom Setting` in the first place.

Third, `Hierarchy Custom Settings` have a `getOrgDefaults()` [method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_custom_settings.htm), which is what you want here and why they are better suited to the task at hand.

```
MyWebhookConfig__c config = MyWebhookConfig__c.getOrgDefaults();
String url = config.URL__c;
String accessKey = config.accessKey;
```

Comment: Interestingly enough (well perhaps for me), I was just about to create a new Custom Metadata type when I realised that I wanted different values for dev/prod. Which made me realise that Custom settings have their place after all. I think that's their most compelling use case, actually.

Comment: I use Hierarchy custom settings to have different data for dev/prod integrations exactly for this reason.  Use the getOrgDefaults method like above, works just fine for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use the `IsSandbox` field on the `Organization` object (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_organization.htm). This object can be queried and then you can branch based off the result of that boolean to use the correct custom setting field.